# How to find common values in 2 variables in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
variable1="ABC
XYZ
DEF"
```

variables have values separated by "\n"

```
variable2="MNO
ABC
PQR"
```

How to find the common value "ABC" from both and store it in a new variable?

Comment: Iterate in both variables and compare the values until you find two identical values (given that the values are separated by a blank as is `\n` it will work with the usual `for x in ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can output those variables to a file, you can use comm.

```
echo "ABC\nXYZ\nDEF" | sort > va1
echo "MNO\nABC\nPQR" | sort > va2
comm -12 va1 va2
```

EDIT:

@ZoltánNagy provided a one line version:

```
comm -12 <(echo -e "b\na\nc"|sort) <(echo -e "a\nb"|sort)
```

Comment: cool; i didn't know comm ;) additionally you can use inline input creation `comm -12 <(echo -e "b\na\nc"|sort) <(echo -e "a\nb"|sort)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply

```
echo "$variable1" | grep -Fx "$variable2"
```

This is portable to POSIX shell.

In the general case, I would recommend using Bash arrays for keeping a list of discrete values in a variable, rather than putting them in a newline-delimited string, assuming you don't care about POSIX compatibility (in which case this question should not be tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)).